# Google Map marker in wrong location

Tags: google-maps

All of my lat/lng locations have been taken off of Google Earth using the mouse.
When I enter the data into Google Maps I have multiple instances where the marker does not show the proper location.  For example:  a marker for lat 38.015986 lng -84.355413 (coordinates for The Aviation Museum of Kentucky) shows up at 38.005754, -84.211968 (again using my mouse pointer to provide lat/lng of marker.)
I can't use geocode because many of my locations do not have addresses - in road medians, internal to 430 acre park, etc.
How do I correct for (or get) the proper lat/lng?

Comment: OP has indicated this was due to an input error.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have the units of your Lat Long incorrectly entered.
Lat and long can be entered as

`hdd.ddddd` (decimal degrees)

`hddd'mm.mmm'` (degrees with decimal minutes)

`hdd'mm'ss.ss''` (degrees, minutes seconds)

This seems likely, since you get close to the correct answer.

If you need to convert between these or any positional grid system and datum I recommend using Garmin Basecamp, it is free.